# Dificuldade em alterar imagem no banco de dados Formulario HTML/PHP

Tags: php, imagem

Fala galera tudo na boa com vocês ?

queria saber se alguém poderia me dar uma luz no fim do túnel hehe, então vamos lá!

Tenho um formulário HTML onde são enviados as informações para o banco e depois os exibe em uma consulta, até ai blz, mas quando vou alterar os dados, ele altera todas as informações, menos a imagem, vi em algum fóruns que teria que apagar a imagem antes de fazer o update no banco, porem ainda não consegui essa proeza, ele ate deleta a imagem, porem não faz o update só insere como se fosse um novo registro. vou postar os códigos aqui, se alguém puder ajudar a corrigir os erros agradeço desde já, abraços!!

---

**inicio.php**

```
 <form method="post" action="processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">

            <input type="submit" class="bnt salvar" value="Enviar"> 
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <h5>Arquivo em anexo: <font color="#00BFFF">*</font></h5> <input type="file" class= "anexo" name="arquivo">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**editar.php**

```
<?php
include ("conexao.php"); //inicia a conexao com o banco 
?>
<html lang ="pt-br">      
<html>
  <head>                     
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../agoravai/css/estilo.css">
  </head>       
            <body>

                    <nav>


                            <ul class="menu">
                            <a href="../agoravai/inicio.php"><li>Inicio</li></a>
                             <a href="../aff/consultaeqp.php"><li>Consulta</a>

                               </ul>

                   </nav>



              </body>




        <?php

$iden = isset($_GET['iden'])?$_GET['iden']:""; //recebe o codigo da pag de consulta      

$iden = $_GET ['codigo'];


$sql = "select * from eqp where codigo = '$iden'"; // consulta no banco de dados 
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$registros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

//recebe os dados    

$codigo = $linhas ['codigo'];
$arquivo = $linhas['arquivo'];



            echo ("


            <tr>

              <form method='post' action='salva_ed.php''>
            <td>Codigo:</td><td> <input type='text' name='codigo' value='"  .   $codigo . "'> </td>  

              <td>anexo:</td><td> <input type='file'name='imagem'></td>

              <br><br>  

             </tr>

      <br><br>

      <input type='submit' class='bnt salvar' value='Salvar'> 



 ");


        }

        ?>


</html>
```

**salva_ed.php**

---

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("conexao.php"); //inicia conexão com o banco 

$arquivo= $_FILES['imagem']['name']; // recebe a imagem da pagina de edição 
$iden = isset($_POST['iden'])?$_POST['iden']:"";  // recebe o codigo do registro    

$iden = $_POST ['codigo']; // codigo registro 

// aqui seria onde ele veifica se existe algo no campo arquivo e o substitui por um valor em branco 
if($arquivo == ""){
    $query =("update eqp set arquivo = '' WHERE codigo='$iden'");
}else{

// aqui seria onde fazia o update da imagem, dando um novo nome e movendo para a pasta de upload 
 if(isset($_FILES['imagem']))
   {
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eqp WHERE codigo = '$id' LIMIT 1");
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão
    $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
    $new_name = $resultado['foto']; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
    $dir = 'upload'; //Diretório para uploads

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo

   }

$imagem = $new_name;

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE eqp set arquivo = '$imagem' WHERE codigo='$id'");

  $result1 = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql,$query);

  // Verifica se o comando foi executado com sucesso
  if(!$result1)
    echo "Registro NÃO alterado.";
  else
    echo "Registro Alterado com sucesso.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Códigos sem eira nem beira. Action do primeiro form `processa.php`. Action do segundo form `salva_ed.php` e nenhum desses dois arquivos existe!

Comment: olá leo, bom dia, o primeiro processa, seria da minha pagina de inicio. Onde são enviados todas as informações (tem mais campos que são enviados mas deixei so o da imagem para ficar mais facil), e no segundo form, seria onde eu ja peguei os dados do banco para editar e enviar para o salva_ed.php onde nessa pagina esta dando o erro "Notice: Undefined index: imagem in C:\xammp\htdocs\agoravai\salva_ed.php on line 5" ele apaga a imagem no banco e deixa em branco